# Integrating the Office 365 and/or Windows Live credentials in to our website like FB and Twitter

Tags: wordpress, azure, office365, windows-live

I have a requirements like this, Integrating the Office 365 logins or Windows Live logins in to our website, means like Facebook and Twitter I will show one button on login page, onclick of that button user needs to redirect to Office 365 login page and needs to fill the login details. After successful authentication user need to redirect back to the site and register to our site as a user. I tried to find API for Office 365 but couldn't able to find any.

This is for WordPress website, I found [WPOffice 365](https://wpoffice365.com/product/azure-ad-user-authentication-wordpress/), but I doubt that will it work for all Office 365 credentials?

One of my friend used this plugin, but he said, he tried many ways but he stuck with configuring the AAD APP and he is continuously getting this error with that plugin. And WPOffice 365 support is paid.

> ERROR: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

And I found [Auth0](https://auth0.com), but I didn't find Office 365 in their providers list.

Can any one have any idea to integrate Office 365 in to our application?

Thanks in advance and any help here is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer my self, [this](https://github.com/psignoret/aad-sso-wordpress) plugin and its working as expected with out any issues.